# As3 Encryption library

Tags: actionscript-3, encryption

Which encryption libraries are available for actionscript 3.0? my preference is on performance compared to price.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look up [as3crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/).

Comment: I've used that but was looking for something faster. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is as3crypto slow? Slower than you were hoping to get from as3?

Comment: I've used this library quite a lot and it is quite fast; no issues thus far communicating over the wire with remote servers.

Answer (score 2):

as3corelib (http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/) also includes md5 and sha 1.

Comment: Avoid using MD5 at all costs, it is extremely insecure